# Помогите сделать из 2 SQL запросов один

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос-в-запросе

Всем хороших выходных!
Помогите сделать один SQL запрос из двух (думаю возможно сделать с помощью вложенности).

Есть **"TableLogin"**:

| № | userIp | userId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 2 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 3 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 4 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 |
| 5 | 180.15.0.1 | 111 |

и есть **"TableSession"**

| № | userIp | userId | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 180.15.0.1 | 222 | mail1@mail.ru |
| 2 | 180.15.0.1 | 555 | mail2@mail.ru |
| 3 | 180.15.0.1 | 333 | mail3@mail.ru |
| 4 | 190.15.0.1 | 777 | mail4@mail.ru |
| 5 | 190.15.0.1 | 111 | mail5@mail.ru |

Нужно одновременно вывести из "TableLogin":

1. TableLogin.userIp
2. Количество одинаковых userIp у userId = 111 (180.15.0.1 - 3 раза, 190.15.0.1 - 2 раза)
3. Общее количество разных UserIp (будет 2 как в примере)
4. Сколько пересечений в таблице "TableSession" по userIp у других userId (userId != 111)

**Ожидаемый результат** для наглядности:

| userIp | UserLoginCount | totalCount | matchesCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 180.15.0.1 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 190.15.0.1 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Мои SQL запросы:
1:

```
SELECT
    userIp,
    COUNT(*) UserLoginCount,
    COUNT(*) OVER() as totalCount,
FROM TableLogin
WHERE (userIp != '')
  AND (userId = 111)
GROUP BY userIp
```

2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    userIp,
    count(userIp) matchesCount
FROM TableSession
WHERE userIp IN (тут массив userIp полученный из запроса #1)
  AND userId  <> 111
GROUP BY userIp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое объединение (без размышлений над логикой):

```sql
SELECT ts.userIp,
       tl.UserLoginCount,
       tl.totalCount,
       count(ts.userIp) matchesCount
FROM TableSession ts
JOIN ( SELECT userIp,
              userId,
              COUNT(*) UserLoginCount,
              COUNT(*) OVER () as totalCount
       FROM TableLogin
       WHERE userId = 111
       GROUP BY userIp ) tl USING (userIp)
WHERE ts.userId  <> tl.userId
GROUP BY ts.userIp;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2f225aa8f5af139ea43f1e6f5febca5

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!